# Openssl on adb shell

Tags: android

I want to run this command:

```
$ openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -nocrypt -in platform.pk8 -out platform.pem
```

But it is resulting:

```
cannot create openssl read only file system.
```

Please give me a solution to this. How can I run this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `adb remount` from the host computer or `mount -o,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock4 /system` from adb shell.